# JSP: How to format an XMLGregorianCalendar within an input tag

Tags: jsp, date-formatting

How to format an XMLGregorianCalendar within an input tag

Hi there everybody

I am stack in newbie problem and I really would appreciate any help. The problem is as follows:

I have an input tag in my JSP

```
<input id="birthDate" name="birthDate" 
    class="form-control input-sm" value="${data.birthDate}" disabled/>
```

It works fine since the output is

```
2021-06-29T08:14:13.041Z
```

I would like to format this XMLGregorianCalendar as dd/MM/yyyy INSIDE the input tag but I just don't get it. I CAN'T change "data.birthDate" type since "data" is an autogenerated class from an WSDL file. I tryed something like following but it didn't work.

```
<%
Calendar calendar = data.getBirthDate.toGregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
formatter.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
String dateString = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
%>
<input id="birthDate" name="birthDate" 
     class="form-control input-sm" value="${dateString}" disabled/>
```

Please, could you help me? Thank you in advance

Regards

Comment: A side note: The "input tag" is an ordenary html input field. Second: What is the output format if you don't use SimpleDateFormat? Third: Use `<%= %>` instead of `${}`to inject the serverside code into clientside code.

Comment: The output format is 2021-06-29T08:14:13.041Z. Thanks

Comment: Have you already tried `<%= dateString %>` instead of `${dateString}`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Reporter. This was the answer

```
<%=dateString%>
```